# Issue with gitlab-runner and strange x509 certificate in my installation of gitlab ee

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm running a server with Gitlab EE 11.7.0-ee (c02f0d4) perfectly on last months.

Running over owned subdomain, with SSL certificate correct,

Using the steps indicated by the Gitlab manuals try installing gitlab-runner

```
curl -L https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/runner/gitlab-

runner/script.deb.sh | sudo bash
 cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-gitlab-runner.pref
 Explanation: Prefer GitLab provided packages over the Debian native ones
 Package: gitlab-runner
 Pin: origin packages.gitlab.com
 Pin-Priority: 1001
 EOF
sudo apt-get install gitlab-runner
```

After this I hav tried to register my first shared runner

1. Go to admin/runners
2. On shel run command for register

```
gitlab-runner register
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=8467 revision=8bb608ff version=11.7.0
Running in system-mode.

Please enter the gitlab-ci coordinator URL (e.g. https://gitlab.com/):
https://gitlab.castris.com/
Please enter the gitlab-ci token for this runner:
zBTcN59V-GGGGGGGGGGG
Please enter the gitlab-ci description for this runner:
[gitlab]: test
Please enter the gitlab-ci tags for this runner (comma separated):
test
ERROR: Registering runner... failed                 runner=zBTcN59V status=couldn't execute POST against https://gitlab.castris.com/api/v4/runners: Post https://gitlab.castris.com/api/v4/runners: x509: certificate is valid for m169-571.powervow.com, not gitlab.castris.com
PANIC: Failed to register this runner. Perhaps you are having network problems
```

```
cat /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800
```